# How do I get Ubuntu option after installation beside a Windows 7?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have installed Ubuntu along side Windows 7. After restart, I got a blank screen. There after I restarted it manually. Now I can't understand, how to select the Ubuntu os. My laptop directly boots into windows 7.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't install GRUB. How did you install it? And also what options did you choose in the installation? I can help you if you answer those questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) in Ubuntu.

---

### Installing Boot Repair

1. Open the Terminal, then type:

   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
2. Press Enter.
3. Then type:

   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
4. Press Enter

### Using Boot Repair

Search for Boot Repair in the dash and launch it. Then click the "Recommended Repair" button and wait until it's finished.

---

Reboot. Does it work now?